# Fix the color of charts in HighCharts

Tags: angularjs, highcharts

I have a high charts which on refresh dynamically data is pushed into the series but everytime the color changes how to fix the color of the charts.I am using angular js and my highchart config object is as follows

```
var chartConfig = {
            credits: {
                enabled: false
            },
            options: {
                colors: ['#058DC7', '#50B432', '#ED561B', '#DDDF00', '#24CBE5', '#64E572', '#FF9655', '#FFF263', '#6AF9C4'],
                chart: {
                    backgroundColor: '#EDEDED',
                    zoomType: 'x',
                    reflow: true
                },
                credits: false
            },
            series: [],
            tooltip: {
                headerFormat: '<span style="font-size:10px">{point.key}</span><table>',
                pointFormat: '<tr><td style="color:{series.color};padding:0">{series.name}: </td>' +
                    '<td style="padding:0"><b>{point.y:.1f} mm</b></td></tr>',
                footerFormat: '</table>',
                shared: true,
                useHTML: true
            },
            legend: {
                enabled: true
            },
            series: [],
            exporting: {
                csv: {
                    dateFormat: '%Y-%m-%d'
                }
            },
            title: {
                text: '',
                style: {
                    display: 'none'
                }
            },
            xAxis: {
                title: {}
            },
            func: function(chart) {
                $timeout(function() {
                    chart.reflow();
                }, 0);
            }
        };
```

Comment: If the colors are changing, then you're not updating the series - you're adding a new one. Show how you're updating the data for more help.

Comment: I am setting the series array to null and then again inserting the values into the series

Comment: Everytime I refresh I make an Ajax call get the data parse it and then insert into the series array

Comment: Right. So you are removing the series and adding a new one. Which makes it a different color. You need to instead use one of the update functions, like **series.update()** or **series.setData()** or **series.addPoint()** | Reference: http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#Series

Comment: can you tell me how to do it, where to add series.update()

Comment: I insert data in the series like this: chartConfig.series.push(regressionForHighchart); do I have write series.update after this

Comment: Can you provide me an example

Comment: So instead of chartConfig.series.push(regression ForHighchart),i will do chartConfig.series[0].update(regression ForHighchart) or chartConfig.series[0].setData(regression ForHighchart)

Comment: Yes - instead of removing and adding series, add your series in the initial chart config options, and use either of those methods to update the existing series.  As Pawel stated in his answer below, you can also set the colors for each series explicitly, so that which ever way the chart gets updated, it will always use the same colors.

Comment: Data comes randomly so as a result I dnt know how many series will get populated....so it is not possible to explicit set the colors

Answer (score 2):

Instead of setting `chartConfig.series[index] = newSeries`, use Highcharts object and method mentioned by @jlbriggs . You can access chart original object as described in the highcharts-ng [FAQ](https://github.com/pablojim/highcharts-ng#faq) (second point).

To explain the problem: each time highcharts-ng recreates series when update arrives. That means series colors are taken as new indexes from `chart.colors` array. So instead of using solution above, you can:

- assign color for each series directly in options:

  ```
  chartConfig.series[index] = { data: [...], color: 'red' };
  ```
- set `chart.colors` to be the same length as number of series you use on the chart:

  ```
  colors: ['#058DC7', '#50B432', '#ED561B'], // for example only three series on the chart
  ```

Comment: Tried with chartConfig.series.update but giving an error as chartConfig.series.update is not a function

Comment: See more info under FAQ section. Don't use it on `chartConfig.series.update` - there's no such method as `update()` in your options.

Comment: Then what to do please help

Comment: Please, see my answer above. Should be something like `config.getHighcharts.series[index].update()` or `config.getHighcharts().series[index].update()`.

Comment: Dere is no specific index i am inserting whole object into the series array

Comment: And that is the reason why you have this issue :) Don't do that. Instead, loop over all `series` array, and update each of the series respectively.